# Paypal: how to give limited access to the success page?

Tags: php, javascript, html, paypal

I have created a paypal pay now button using the button generator, if the user have successfully paid, he'll be redirected to `example.com/success`

in the `success` directory, i have an `index.html` containing some javascript telling the user that he'll be redirected to the site

now if the user entered `example.com/success` he'll see the success page even if he didn't pay.

So how to let only those who pay see the page?

By limiting the access to that page, I will be able to know who paid and get the Ip address
just like I did on [this site](http://musicville.fm) with my friend using xml, without using IPN. I know which Ip download which song and when. I want to use the same method on my site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't stop them going there, but you can check with PayPal that anyone who comes there has been legitimately sent there via PayPal. PayPal have PHP code you can copy-and-paste to do this on their site - https://www.paypal.com/th/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/pdt-codesamples-pop-outside

If someone just enters the URL to the success page, it will fail this check in the PayPal code:

```
else if (strcmp ($lines[0], "FAIL") == 0) {
// log for manual investigation
}
```

You could add code in that section to log what happens, redirect to an error page instead etc...

On a related note, using PayPal's encrypted payments option is also a good idea. It's a bit tricky to set up, but it means all the data you send to PayPal can't be read/modified by anyone.

Comment: can you answer this question sir? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197269/how-to-make-paypal-button-fields-required